# one time install flex AIR app

Tags: apache-flex, air, installation

I have to export my flex air app to `project.air`  file

But condition is `one time installaton`.
for security reasons.
How can I achieve this? any Idea?

Comment: What does `one time installation` mean exactly?

Comment: @RIAstar after installing air app in 1 system, it should not allow to install in second system with same .air file.

Comment: The only way I envision making something like this work is to enforce a "call home" architecture/licensing scheme.